# What is the systemd-networkd equivalent of post-up? (dynamic bridge MAC configuration)

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, bridge, systemd

In Linux distributions that use `/etc/network/interfaces` (such as Debian) I could get a (kernel) bridge to use the MAC48 address of one of its static bridge slave interfaces, such as a built in `wlan0`, using `post-up`, as in:

```
 post-up ip link set br0 address `cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`
```

This ensured that both 1) each cloned system used its very own unique MAC48 (the one from the unique wlan0), and 2) the bridge MAC kept stable even when hot-plugging further bridge interfaces with lower MAC48's.

Does systemd-networkd support any kind of `post-up` commands that can be run after a network (or netdev) has been brought up? I've tried to find such a thing, but may have missed it.

Or is the correct way in systemd completely different, i.e. to have a device unit, and a service that wraps the `ip link...` command and depends on the device unit? If so, how would the device unit and the service unit files look like?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that due to the heavy modular concept of `systemd` and `systemd-networkd` the scripting question needs to be tackled from a different angle: instead of looking for scripting with the bridge `.netdev` definition, the `systemd` way is to have a (very small) one-shot `.service` unit that is *wanted by* the bridge `.netdev`.

> **As a side note:** it seems that in more recent Linux kernels, the kernel
>   bridges actually don't use the dynamically changing lowest MAC48
>   scheme for the bridge MAC48 anymore. Instead, they create a static
>   MAC48 for the bridge itself. So, in the very strict sense this
>   solution is not really needed anymore, unless one prefers to use a
>   "real" hardware MAC48; which is what is done here in the following
>   service unit.

The necessary new service unit (in lieu of the old `post-up` from `/etc/network/interfaces`) lives in `/etc/systemd/system/bridge-stable-mac.service` and assigns the MAC48 from (built-in, fixed) `wlan0` to the bridge itself:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/echo 'br0 available, setting MAC ' `/bin/cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/sbin/ip link set br0 address `/bin/cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`"

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-br0.device
```

The central point here is the `WantedBy=` clause: whenever `br0` starts, then this service should be run (exactly once, `Type=oneshot`). Systemd is really neat here, as it doesn't need to edit the existing device definition in order to add our dependency, but instead calculates this dependency using our inverse `WantedBy=` link. This is really where I think that `systemd` does shine.

The service unit above assumes that your bridge is named `br0`. You should use a corresponding `.netdev` file to define this bridge `br0`. For instance, in `/etc/systemd/network/10-br0.netdev`:

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

When it comes to hotplugging bridge ports, `systemd` actually does this already out-of-the-box, which is very neat; in `/etc/systemd/network/10-br0-ports.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0 wlan0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

That's it!

Comment: I wonder if `RemainAfterExit=yes` is needed for the service.